# Type inference inconsistency between toList and toBuffer

Tags: scala, type-inference

As per the example below, calling `xs.toList.map(_.toBuffer)` succeeds, but `xs.toBuffer.map(_.toBuffer)` fails. But when the steps in the latter are performed using an intermediate result, it succeeds. What causes this inconsistency?

```
scala> "ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(ab, cd)

scala> res0.map(_.toBuffer)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Char]] = ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(a, b), ArrayBuffer(c, d))

scala> "ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer.map(_.toBuffer)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toBuffer)
              "ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer.map(_.toBuffer)
                                              ^

scala> "ab-cd".split("-").toList.map(_.toBuffer)
res3: List[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Char]] = List(ArrayBuffer(a, b), ArrayBuffer(c, d))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the definitions of `toBuffer` and `toList`:

```
def toBuffer[A1 >: A]: Buffer[A1]
def toList: List[A]
```

As you can see, `toBuffer` is generic, while `toList` is not. 
The reason for this difference is - I believe - that `Buffer` is invariant, while `List` is covariant.

Let's say that we have the following classes:

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
```

Because `List` is covariant, you can call `toList` on an instance of `Iterable[Bar]` and treat the result as a `List[Foo]`.
If `List` where invariant, this would not be the case.
`Buffer` being invariant, if `toBuffer` was defined as `def toBuffer: Buffer[A]` you would similarly not be able to treat the result
of `toBuffer` (on an instance of `Iterable[Bar]`) as an instance  of `Buffer[Foo]`  (as `Buffer[Bar]` is not a sub-type of `Buffer[Foo]`, unlike for  lists).
But by declaring `toBuffer` as `def toBuffer[A1 >: A]` (notice the added type parameter `A1`), we get back the possibility to have `toBuffer` return an instance of `Buffer[Foo]` :
all we need is to explcitly set `A1` to Foo, or let the compiler infer it (if `toBuffer` is called at a site where a `Buffer[Foo]` is expected).

I think this explains the reason why `toList` and `toBuffer` are defined differently.
Now the problem with this is that `toBuffer` is generic, and this can badly affect inference.

When you do this:

```
"ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer
```

You never explicitly say that `A1` is `String`, but because `"ab-cd".split("-")` has unambiguously the type `Array[String]`, the compiler knows that `A` is `String`.
It also knows that `A1 >: A` (in `toBuffer`), and without any further constraint, it will infer `A1` to be exactly `A`, in other words `String`.
So in the end the whole expression returns a `Buffer[String]`.

But here's the thing: in scala, type inference happens in an expression as a whole. 
When you have something like `a.b.c`, you might expect that scala will infer an exact type
for `a`, then from that infer an exact type for `a.b`, and finally for `a.b.c`. Not so. 
Type inference is *deferred* to the whole expression `a.b.c` (see scala specification "6.26.4 Local Type Inference
", "case 1: selections")

So, going back to your problem, in the expression `"ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer.map(_.toBuffer)`, the sub-expression `"ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer` is **not** typed `Buffer[String]`, but instead
it stays typed as something like `Buffer[A1] forSome A1 >: String`. In other words, `A1` is not fixed, we just carry the constraint `A1 >: String` to the next step of inference.
This next step is `map(_.toBuffer)`, where `map` is defined as `map[C](f: (B) ⇒ C): Buffer[B]`. Here `B` is actually the same as `A1`, but at this point `A1` 
is still not fully known, we only know that `A1 >: String`.
Here lies our problem. The compiler needs to know the exact type of the anonymous function `(_.toBuffer)` (simply because instantiating a `Function1[A,R]` requires to know the exact types of `A` and `R`, just like for any generic type).
So you need to tell him explcitly somehow, as it was not able to infer it exactly.

This means you need to do either:

```
"ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer[String].map(_.toBuffer)
```

Or:

```
"ab-cd".split("-").toBuffer.map((_:String).toBuffer)
```